# Unable to display data received as object from backend ,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects

I am fetching data from the backend, it has a particular sub-part called headers which further has an additional name:value pairs . 
 like this - `data : { headers : {name:"Nishant", value:"random" } }`, I want to display all the fields inside a modal , When I try to use `Object.keys()` , this error  is thrown - "cannot convert undefined or null to object".

```
render(){
 return(
   let request_data = this.props.head // has the entire data
   let data = request_data.headers //contains the headers section to be displayed.
   <div className="modal-body">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-lg-6">
              {
                <div>
                  {// want to display the headers data here }
                  { (request_data.body !== '') ? <div>Body : {request_data.body}</div> : ''}
                </div>
              }
              </div>
           </div>
    </div>
 );
}
```

Not Sure what to do as I tried Using `Object.keys` but an error is thrown saying "cannot convert undefined or null to object". Although by Using JSON.stringify() I am getting the result but not in the expected look and feel.

Comment: so if its { "data": { "headers": { name: "Nishant", value: "random" } } } , how would i have to proceed ?

Comment: The key value mentioned in the question is not json and hence you get the error. This is a valid json "{ "data": { "headers": { "name": "Nishant", "value": "random" } } }"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check header is not undefined before get values;

```
            <div className="col-lg-6">
                {
                    <div>
                        {request_data.header ? Object.values(request_data.header).map(value => value) : null}

                        {(request_data.body !== '') ? <div>Body : {request_data.body}</div> : ''}
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
```

Comment: If i do that only the value pairs are getting displayed , i need the entire name:value to be displayed .

Comment: yes it is working , i used Object.keys instead of Object.values

Answer (score 1):

render the text in a `<pre>` tag and use `JSON.stringify`

```
<pre>{JSON.stringify(request_data.body,null,2)}</pre>
```

Comment: Yes Had , Tried that , although i am getting the requested headers but additional { } at the start and end are also getting displayed which is not needed .

Comment: You can slice those `{}` from the string that you are getting from `JSON.stringify`

`const dataString = JSON.stringify(request_data.body,null,2); 
<pre>{dataString.slice(3, dataString.length-3)}</pre>`

Answer (score 1):

If a valid response is received. 
For Example:

```
{
"data": {
    "headers": {
        "name": "Nishant",
        "value": "random"
    }
}
}

var responseData = JSON.parse('{ "data": { "headers": { name: "Nishant", value: "random" } } }')
```

The first option will display the value in data object and the second will display the value inside the headers object.

```
<pre>responseData.data</pre> 
<pre>responseData.data.headers</pre>
```

Comment: I tried , i am getting an error message of unexpected termination of JSON input